# Difference between a method with void and a constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

What is the difference between using a method with void, and a constructor? For instance:

```
public class Time {
    public void getMethod() {

    }

    public Time() {

    }

}
```

Where do I use what?
Thank you

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Call a method on an already-created object.  Use `new Time()` to call the constructor and to create the object.

Comment: A constructor returns the new object, as such a void parameter would be madness. A method with void on the other hand returns nothing

Comment: What is your doubt?  I assume you know that constructors are used when objects are created.

Comment: @RichardTingle Technically a constructor initialises an object which has already been created.  Constructor don't return anything.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Indeed, I (sort of) know that, but its overall effect is that you now hold in your hands a reference to a new object

Comment: @RichardTingle At the byte code level, constructors always take a `this` argument and return `void` (Actually `V` for void)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Interesting, you learn something new every day

Comment: @RichardTingle In fact at the byte code, the `new` object instruction and the constructor call is separate, although why that would be is not clear to me.  BTW Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class) will create an instance of a class without calling a constructor (even a new Enum ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are methods that belong to a class that are associated with its creation. When you declare an object using Object a = new **Object()**; This is where constructors are invoked.

You should use constructors to organize any data that you'll need for the rest of the class. For example, if you are making a Time class, the Time constructor might get the current time and set it in a variable to use later.

Other methods are simply that. They are the methods that do some calculations or work for the class. For example, you might have a method that accepts a date and returns the days between the date entered, and the current date.

Answer (score 3):

1. Constructor is called after creation of a `new Object()`. Typically to do some initialization, to prepare the object. Methods - you call them when you like.
2. Constructor can be called only once on a certain object. Methods can be called many times.
3. Constructor can't be `static`, because it would be not logical, `static` says "belongs to class, not an object". Methods can be `static`.

Comment: +1 Constructors can also set `final` fields and *must* call a parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

'void' is simply the return type of the method.

Constructors do not have return types.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is used to create a new object. Its use leads to the return of a reference to a new object (although technically the constructor does not return the reference itself). As such void would be a meaningless keyword for a contructor. It is used as `Object o=new Object(parametersIfApplicable)`

On the other hand a method with a void return parameter returns nothing (but would usually change the internal data within the object (or less frequently change one of the objects passed to it); otherwise calling it would be pointless).

#### Summary

- Calling a contructor leads to a new object and returns a reference to it
- A (non static) method is called on an existing object to do some work; it returns nothing

Comment: A constructor doesn't actually return the new object; if it did, a derived class which chained to the parent's constructor would receive an object of the parent's type rather than its own.  A constructor sets up a newly-created "blank" object which is passed to it; unlike most methods, however, a constructor may only be called on an object which has been not been touched in any way since its creation.

Comment: @supercat, indeed, I tried to make that clear within my "technically" section.  My point was that it is called "in the context of" returning a new object

Comment: My point is that there's no "normal" way for a base-class method to produce an object of a derived class it knows nothing about, but when a chained base-class constructor returns, its caller will be a derived class object.  Having the code which calls the constructor generate the object is a common way to achieve that, though not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

A void method specifically does not return any data or object. Pragmatically, a constructor does not return anything.

From a hardware perspective, it initializes the information given at construction allocated by the object declaration by the caller; Doughty provides a broad overview under "[References to and Creating Objects](http://cs.gmu.edu/~jdoughty/cs161/java03.pdf)".

In order to use the method, `getMethod()`, you must create an instance of the class `Time` which is done by constructing its object defined by its constructor.

`Time currentTime; //Declaration of object only allocates space in memory for it`
`currentTime = new Time() //Constructs an instance of Time`
`//and assigns the object reference to variable currentTime`

Then using the method with return of void:

`currentTime.getMethod();`

Simply calls the method so it performs its tasks. It returns no data or object, but control back to where it was called.

Answer (score 0):

Most of an object's methods will be called the same way when invoked by an object under construction as when invoked from anywhere else.  Constructors are different.  A constructor is a special sort of `void` method which cannot be called directly from "normal" code.  Instead, all constructor calls must take one of two forms:

- A call made at the *very beginning* of one constructor to a another constructor in either the present class or superclass.
- A call generated by the system as part of the following sequence (pseudocode given for `x = new Foo(123);`):

  ```
  // "Magical" system routine to create an object without running constructors
  Foo temp = InternalSystemMagic.CreateNewObject([foo's type]); 
  temp.Foo_constructor(p1); // Now invoke the constructor
  x = temp; // Note that if the constructor throws, x will not get set.
  ```

Note that the compiler can produce code which will first create an object of type `Foo` without running the constructors, and then call a constructor on the newly-created type, even though neither operation would be legitimate without the other.